# Jenkins unable to build on kubernetes setup

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

I have a problem with Jenkins build and this is what I am seeing in the build log:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘ci’
```

I am not sure what does that actually means.

I have tried to check the configuration under "Configure Clouds" in Jenkins and it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest few changes do it like this

1. Keep everything blank for `jenkins tunnel`. Jenkins will automatically will pick it up.
2. If you deployed this jenkins instance in kubernetes cluster then please use internal address for `jenkins_url` like `http://jenkins.infrastructure.svc` i assume your jenkins service name is `jenkins` and it is `ClusterIP`
3. For Pod template you can just use `name` and `labels` and remove container template section. kubernetes will pick it up default.
4. Please use the same label to schedule job as agent means you gave the label name different and using as diffrent means your jenkins looking for `ci` agent which is not present so you should replace with `jenkins-jenkins-slave` in your pipeline

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will check it out and update #4 and re-test it. For number 1) can you be more specific what it means `jenkins tunnel`

Comment: I tried to update the label to `jenkins-jenkins-slave` but now I am getting error: 
`‘Jenkins’ doesn’t have label ‘jenkins-jenkins-slave’`.

Comment: @Boban in jenkins go to manage jenkins >> Configure Global Security >> Agents >> set the Fixed 50000 as value. Then try to run jenkins job.